# phonegap apps for quotes using android

Tags: android, cordova

i have developed one app using phonegap,jquery mobile for android using webview and data is directly coming from server but it does not look like native app and google is not showing this app in top 250 .

i want to make my quotes app like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=all.quotes.motivationalquotes

the above app is also developed using phonegap and looks very much like native app.

i am not getting any clue how to do this.if any guide will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap uses an embedded web browser to display web pages created with html, css and javascript. 
plus it has a way to communicate with the device, to push notification for example.
you can work with so many javascript libraries to create the look and feel of a native app, angularjs or jquery mobile these are the best ones.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with Phonegap to make it look like native in One Page Webpage. Ie., If you have multiple tabs then make # tag to avoid server load for each tab. That makes app work faster and make user comfortable.